# Context Sensitive Grammar for the language $\{a^n b^n c^{2+k}\mid n \ge 1, 0 \le k\le 1\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I'm studying for my final exam and come up with this exercise with no idea how to find the production rule of this grammar.

I need help. Thanks all of you! :)

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Would you please add any of your attempts towards a solution *to the question text*? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this just a simple variant of the grammar for $\{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 1\}$? can you be more specific about what you need help with?

Comment: I need to find the production rule of this grammar

Comment: Yes, we know what the exercise is. What do you need help with? Be more specific than "I need help solving the exercise."

Comment: I need help to find the production rule of the language. Something like S -> aAb. Sorry for my English because i've not been taught this subject in English

Comment: @HuyVũ A question saying "no idea" is one of the most difficult questions to answer. One possible answer should be asking you to read the course material again. Try finding examples that looks similar to the problem at hand. Try finding rules, lemmas, theorems and just about anything that might be applicable to the current situation. You should be able to find at least some. Then you might have be able to solve the problem. Or you could raise a more meaningful question, such as "I thought this rule should be applicable. However, that condition cannot be met. What can I do?"

Comment: Thanks for your advise @Apass.Jack

Comment: Please check whether this is actually the question you want answered. There is no need at all for a context sensitive grammar, a context free grammar will do just fine and is quite trivial. I very much suspect there is a “2” that is supposed to be an “n” or “2n”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the hint.

#### The grammar of a union is the union of the grammars.

That is, the grammar for $L_1$ and $L_2$ is the "union" of $G_1$ and $G_2$, where $G_1, G_2$ is the grammar for $L_1$ and $L_2$ respectively. Instead of a formal definition, let me use an example to illustrate the meaning of the strategy.

Suppose the grammar for language $L_1$ is:
$\quad S\to aSbS \mid ST \mid \epsilon$
$\quad T\to Tab \mid \epsilon$
Suppose the grammar for language $L_2$ is:
$\quad S\to bSaS \mid T $
$\quad T\to aT \mid \epsilon$
Then the grammar for $L_1\cup L_2$ is:
$\quad S\to S_1 \mid S_2$
$\quad S_1\to aS_1bS_1 \mid S_1T_1 \mid \epsilon$
$\quad T_1\to T_1ab \mid \epsilon$
$\quad S_2\to bS_2aS_2 \mid T_2 $
$\quad T_2\to T_2a \mid \epsilon$
where all nonterminals for $L_1$ are added subscript ${}_1$ and all nonterminals for $L_2$ are added subscript ${}_2$ and, finally, a new rule $S\to S_1\mid S_2$ is added.

Can you see how to decompose the language given in the title into smaller pieces so as to apply this strategy?

Comment: Welcome to the site!